# Перенаправлять ли с адресов без '/'?

Tags: seo

Как для поисковиков лучше, когда адреса без `/` перенаправляются на адреса с этим символом или когда вместо таких дублей выводится 404 ошибка?

Comment: На дворе 2018 год. Неужели вы думаете, что поисковики настолько тупые, что до сих пор считают адрес со слешем и без - дублями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенаправляйте на адрес без символа `/`. Если руководствоваться здравым смыслом: для рядового пользователя нет большой разницы заканчивается этим символом адрес или нет, а вот если вы будете перенаправлять на страницу с ошибкой, это может вызвать непонимание. Та же история и с поисковиками, например, если кто-то будет искать страницу на сайте по url. Вот поэтому, как мне кажется, будет правильно сделать переадресацию на страницу без символа, а не на 404 ошибку.